# Selenium IDE Sendkeys() is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to create a script using Selenium IDE. Trying to enter phone number in the text box field, which accepts the number in the specified format as "(999) 999 - 999"

[image]

I have used Sendkeys function which doesn't works for this text box.

Is there anyway to enter numbers to this text box?

Comment: can you give us the HTML of the textbox and also the selenium command with which you tried ot access the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After SendKeys Command. Can you try using fireEvent command. It will trigger the event for that particular control.